# how to increment stage by condition in python pandas with groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have data coming from two Groups A and B. The task is to monitor change, and if change (Leap) is bigger that 4, the Stage is set higher by 1. The data is ordered (time series).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'Leap': [1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1]})

# First set Stage to 1 for all:
df['Stage'] = 1

# Function to find first leap -> set Stage to two.
def setStage2(df):
    df.loc[df['Leap'] > 4, 'Stage'] = 2
    return df

# Apply function by group:
df.groupby('Group').apply(setStage2)
```

[image: First trial]

This is how far I could get. The Stage should be incremental: once on Stage 2, no going back to 1. This is how the result should look like:

[image: This is how the Stage should look like]

So how to fill Stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution combining `groupby` and `transform`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Leap': [1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1]
})

df["Stage"] = df.groupby("Group").Leap.transform(lambda x: (x > 4).cumsum()) + 1
```

You can also use `apply` instead of `transform` in this case.